# How do I display the Summernote images which are encoded in base64 in flask application?

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, summernote

I am creating a blog application using flask, I used Summernote editor for text area, the image content are converting into base64 code, and I was unable to display the images that I uploaded into MYSQL database.

```
{{ blog.post | safe }}
```

All the post content is displaying except images, instead broken images are displaying.How to deal with this situation?

Comment: What do you see in the resulting HTML output? Are there broken images? No `<img>` tags at all?

Comment: @ceejayoz I see a broken image.

Comment: When you view source, what does the `<img>` tag look like? Can you put the output HTML somewhere so people can look?